# Change an user password on SAMBA with Python

Tags: python, linux, passwords, samba

I shall write a script using Python to change an user password on a SAMBA server.
I never learned Python and now I tried different things on my VirtualBox with Ubuntu.
With this code I can change (or better delete and set a new) password of an user in my VirtualBox.
But will it also work on the Server? 
I have no clue. Please help me. Thank you!

```
from subprocess import Popen

uname = raw_input("Username: ")
proc = Popen(['/usr/bin/sudo', '/usr/bin/passwd', uname, '--d'])
proc.communicate()
proc = Popen(['/usr/bin/sudo', '/usr/bin/passwd', uname])
proc.communicate()
```

Answer (score 1):

user2960552's solution doesn't work without user interaction. The following fixes that:

```
def create_or_update_samba_user(username, password):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'smbpasswd', '-a', username], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.communicate(input=password + '\n' + password + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment that's why here is a slightly different version from Nyman:

```
def create_or_update_samba_user(username, password):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'smbpasswd', '-a', '-s', username], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.communicate(input=password + '\n' + password + '\n')
```

This is the version that does not require any user intervention. The '-s' tells smbpasswd to take the password from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_smb_password(username, password):
    try:
        # Set Samba password
        command = ['sudo', 'smbpasswd', '-a', '-s', username]
        input_data = f"{password}\n{password}\n".encode('utf-8')

        subprocess.run(command, input=input_data, check=True)

        print(f"Samba password set successfully for user '{username}'.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
```

**encode('utf-8')** method used to convert the string input_data to a bytes-like object before passing it to **subprocess.run**.

Answer (score -2):

So if I read right this should work?

```
from subprocess import Popen

uname = raw_input("Username: ")
proc = Popen(['/usr/bin/sudo', '/usr/bin/smbpasswd', '-a', uname])
proc.communicate()
```

Thank you for your help!

Sadly I don't have access to the Server yet so I can't test it. And I don't want to give a not-working script to the server-administrator.